# Covariance of two R.V's and a specific conditional probability

Tags: probability, covariance

Question:

> Suppose that X is a random variable taking on only the values 0 and 1 and that Y is a random variable taking on only the values −1,0,1. It is known that Var(X) = 1/4, Var(Y ) = 1/2 and E[Y ] = 0. In addition, it is known that P(X = 0|Y = 0) = 0. Find Cov(X,Y ).

I can't seem to figure this question out. I have done pretty much everything that comes to mind, but always reached a dead end.
The only thing I've conclusively managed to do is find out the probability mass function of both X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Let us draw joint p.m.f. as a table

\begin{array}{lr|c|c|c|c}            %   \hline
        &  Y=b    &    -1     & \, 0\,  &  \, 1 \,& \mathbb P(X=a)    \\[-1mm]
X=a     &         &           &         &         &      \\  \hline
  0     &         &    x       &   y     &    z    &  x+y+z=p   \\  \hline
  1     &         &    u      &   v     &    w    &  u+v+w=1-p \\  \hline
\mathbb P(Y=b)&   &    x+u    &  y+v    &  z+w    &   1 \\  
\end{array}
and start from $\mathbb P(X=0\mid Y=0)$. Can you find $y=\mathbb P(X=0,Y=0)$ from here?

> $y=0$

Next, $Var(X)=1/4=p-p^2$, Find $p$ from here.

> $p=\frac12$

$\mathbb E[Y]=0$ implies both $x+u=z+w$ and 
$$Var(Y)=\mathbb E[Y^2]=(-1)^2(x+u)+1^2(z+w)=x+u+z+w=\frac12.$$
Then $y+v=\frac12$ too. So $v=\frac12$ and $x+u=z+w=\frac14$.

\begin{array}{lr|c|c|c|c}            %   \hline
        &  Y=b    &    -1     & \, 0\,  &  \, 1 \,& \mathbb P(X=a)    \\[-1mm]
X=a     &         &           &         &         &      \\  \hline
  0     &         &           &   0     &        &  \frac12   \\  \hline
  1     &         &          &   \frac12     &        &  \frac12 \\  \hline
\mathbb P(Y=b)&   &    \frac14    &  \frac12    &  \frac14    &   1 \\  
\end{array}
You can fill the rest cells in the table.

Comment: That is pretty much exactly how far I had gotten (except I didn't write it in table form). I'm not sure how to proceed from here though, since I'm not sure what other info we have?

Comment: You do not need other info to fill rest of the table. Can you find $u$ and $w$?